# three.js issue: multiple animations on character switch but don't play

Tags: javascript, three.js

Newbie here.  I've loaded an ,fbx character, plus additional animation clips from Mixamo.  The idea is that the animations switch when a key ("Q") is clicked.  When run, the character loads and plays the first animation clip.  On key press, the animation clips changes but the animation doesn't play.  Here's where I'm currently at.. [character anim](http://www.e-nimation.com/dev/three/Moe.html)

Here's the relevant code snippet...

```js
        let Actions = [];
        let action;
        let animPaths = [ "./models/T-Pose.fbx","./models/Walking.fbx","./models/Running.fbx","./models/Idle.fbx" , "./models/Dancing.fbx"];
        let pathIDs = ["t-pose","walking", "running", "idle", "dancing"];
        let moe;
        let mixer;

        
        const loader = new FBXLoader();

        loader.load("./models/T-Pose.fbx", function(object){
            object.scale.set(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
           /* object.traverse(function(child){
                if(child.isMesh){
                    child.material = material;
                }
            })*/
            moe = object;
            moe.position.y = -70;
            mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(object);
            action = mixer.clipAction(object.animations[0]);
            Actions.push(action);
            //action.play();
            scene.add(object);
            loadNextAnimation(loader);
            
        });


        function loadNextAnimation(loader){
            for(let i=1;i<animPaths.length;i++){
                
                loader.load(animPaths[i], (object) =>{
                    mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(moe);
                    Actions.push(mixer.clipAction(object.animations[0]));
                    scene.add(object);
                    action = Actions[i];
                    mixer.stopAllAction();
                    action.play();
                })
            }
            
        }


        let i = 0;
        let fwd = true;
        document.onkeydown = function(event) {
            // 81 = q
            
            if(event.keyCode == 81){
                if(i < 1) fwd = true;
                if(i > Actions.length) fwd = false;
                if(fwd){
                    i++;
                }else{
                    i--;
                }
                
                action = Actions[i];
                mixer.stopAllAction();
                //mixer.reset();
                action.play();
                
                console.log("i = " + i);
                console.log(animPaths[i]);
                document.getElementById("testtext").value = "currentClip = "+pathIDs[i];
                animate();
            }
        };
```

Can someone tell me where I'm screwing up?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found (thanks, Harold).  I created a mixer when I uploaded the T-Pose.  Then, in *loadNextAnimation(loader)* function, I created a new mixer every time a new animation was loaded, overwriting the previous mixer. Simply removing the line **mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(moe);** solved the problem.